# add aliases on osx terminal for all users

Tags: bash, terminal

how add aliases for all users in my Mac OSX El Capitan? I try add folder `/etc/profile.d/customization.sh*`

`*aliases hear`

but it's not working. And *.sh script runing but not add aliases even in the current session
this my script

```
alias dir='ls -l'
alias ll='ls -l'
alias la='ls -la'
alias l='ls -alF'
# cat /etc/profile.d/customization.sh 
alias ls-l='ls -l'
alias o='less'
alias ..='cd ..'
alias ...='cd ../..'
alias cd..='cd ..'
alias rd=rmdir
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias md='mkdir -p'
alias vi=vim
```

chmod +x script is made

Comment: Note that such files are loaded once, when you log in. If you edit them, test its functionality by logging out and in again.

Comment: this file not execute in console. i don't no why. If i run "alias dir='ls -l' in terminal it's ok, but if I run this file nothing happens

Comment: Run? You don't have to run it, but source --> `source /etc/profile.d/customization.sh*`.

Comment: Files under `/etc/profile.d` aren't automatically sourced; they are typically processed from a site-specific `/etc/profile`. The one that ships with El Capitan does not do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am solved this problem. Need add aliases in the end file /etc/bashrc

example:

```
sudo nano /etc/bashrc

alias dir='ls -l'
```

save file and reboot or logout